# Using PDO and failing to insert a record

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am having a slight issue adding a record into the database.

For some reason it is not adding the record into the database.

I have a form in HTML and serialize it with jQuery to use in an AJAX request. I know this works as I used to use it with the old mysql commands.

This is what I have in the insert.php file:

```
$ln=($_POST['lastname']);
$fn=($_POST['firstname']);
$dob=($_POST['dob']);
$un=($_POST['username']);

$a1=($_POST['address1']);
$a2=($_POST['address2']);
$town=($_POST['town']);
$county=($_POST['county']);
$pc=($_POST['postcode']);
$country=($_POST['country']);
$lat=($_POST['lat']);
$lng=($_POST['lng']);

$lp=($_POST['landline']);
$mp=($_POST['mobile']);
$e1=($_POST['email1']);
$e2=($_POST['email2']);

$web=($_POST['web']);
$notes=($_POST['notes']);
$fb=($_POST['fbid']);
$tw=($_POST['twitter']);
$cat=($_POST['cat']);

$it=($_POST['Time']); 
$idate=($_POST['Date']); 
$iip=($_POST['ipaddress']);
$ib=($_POST['browser']);
$ios=($_POST['os']);
```

These are the posted values being used from the form.

I then have the following queries (I have 5 different ones as they are writing to 5 tables. As I say, this worked with the old mysql commands, but not the PDO commands.

```
$sqlp = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO ".PERSON." (lastname, firstname, dob, adbkid) VALUES(:ln, :fn, :dob, :un)");
$sqlp->execute();
$idp = $conn->lastInsertId();

$sqla = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO ".ADDRESS." (address1, address2, town, county, postcode, country, lat, lng, personID) VALUES (:a1, :a2, :town, :county, :pc, :country, :lat, :lng, :un)");
$sqla->execute();
$ida = $conn->lastInsertId();

$sqlc = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO ".CONTACT." (landline, mobile, email1, email2, personID) VALUES (:lp, :mp, :e1, :e2, :un)");
$sqlc->execute();
$idc = $conn->lastInsertId();

$sqlm = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO ".MISC." (web, notes, photo, fbid, twitter, cat, personID) VALUES (:web, :notes, :pic, :fb, :tw, :cat, :un)");
$sqlm->execute();
$idm = $conn->lastInsertId();

$sqlv = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO ".VARI." (Time, Date, ipaddress, browser, os, personID) VALUES (:it, :idate, :ip, :ib, :ios, :un)"); 
$sqlv->execute();
$idv = $conn->lastInsertId();

$sqlp->bindValue(':ln', $ln);
$sqlp->bindValue(':fn', $fn);
$sqlp->bindValue(':dob', $dob);
$sqlp->bindValue(':un', $un);

$sqla->bindValue(':a1', $a1);
$sqla->bindValue(':a2', $a2);
$sqla->bindValue(':town', $town);
$sqla->bindValue(':county', $county);
$sqla->bindValue(':pc', $pc);
$sqla->bindValue(':country', $country);
$sqla->bindValue(':lat', $lat);
$sqla->bindValue(':lng', $lng);

$sqlc->bindValue(':lp', $lp);
$sqlc->bindValue(':mp', $mp);
$sqlc->bindValue(':e1', $e1);
$sqlc->bindValue(':e2', $e2);

$sqlm ->bindValue(':web', $web);
$sqlm ->bindValue(':notes', $notes);
$sqlm ->bindValue(':pic', $pic);
$sqlm ->bindValue(':fb', $fb);
$sqlm ->bindValue(':tw', $tw);
$sqlm ->bindValue(':cat', $cat);

$sqlv ->bindValue(':it', $it);
$sqlv ->bindValue(':idate', $idate);
$sqlv ->bindValue(':iip', $iip);
$sqlv ->bindValue(':ib', $ib);
$sqlv ->bindValue(':ios', $ios);
```

I have ran these with a try catch to see if I can figure out what is going on and I get the following error:

```
"SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound"
```

I have echoed out what is being put into each of the values and it corresponds with what I have in entered into the form.

I am also trying to echo out the last inserted ID's for each table and it isn't echoing that out.

I have had a look around Google and php.net and here and from what I read I am doing everything as they say I should be.

I am at a loss as to what is happening.

If you had any pointers they would be most welcome.

Comment: You should bind value before execute() call

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to bind the params first and then execute it

i.e:

```
$sqlp = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO ".PERSON." (lastname, firstname, dob, adbkid) VALUES(:ln, :fn, :dob, :un)");
$sqlp->bindValue(':ln', $ln);
$sqlp->bindValue(':fn', $fn);
$sqlp->bindValue(':dob', $dob);
$sqlp->bindValue(':un', $un);
$sqlp->execute();
$idp = $conn->lastInsertId();
...
```

Comment: I have bound the values before executing it and it is not returning anything to say it has been entered into the database and the record just isn't there

Comment: configure pdo to report errors by `$conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );` and use `print_r($sqlp->errorInfo());` so get the error

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I am trying and it would appear that it is failing on executing all the statements. I have tried them one by one and they appear to work. Is this allowed to execute them this way? Just can't seem to get my head around it. Thanks

Comment: @chreese: I did get an error as one of the placeholders was wrong. It is now inserting the records, but for some reason the success function is not displaying anything to show the insert was successful

Comment: When I am posting the form through $.ajax I look at the console and it is showing a 200 successful response, it just isn't pasting the echo response in a div like it used to

Comment: well you are not printing any message in your code as far as i can see

Comment: I do have an echo in there. It is echo "$fn $ln was successfully inserted"; This doesn't show though